# How to show previously selected Parameter by default

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssas, history

I have an SSRS report in which I've a Data Parameter. I want something like: Suppose I select a Date 10JAN2014, then when I return again to the same report I want the date parameter already set to 10JAN2014. Is it possible in SSRS ?

Answer (score 0):

There is few options...
You need to create a table , use update statement which will put currently selected value ,then in 
parameter properties  use that column as default value.
You can also try to extract that value from execution log from report server.